# Find an element that contains id of selector + text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm confused as to how I should go about doing this.

My page is using PHP to take product codes off a database and using them to generate ids for elements. For example: `$("#touch-'.$productcode.'")` and `$("#popup-'.$productcode.'")`

I need to make it so when an element is clicked on, jQuery will find an element in the document which contains the last 11 characters of the selector's id plus additional text.

e.g. the selector `$(this)` (which has a generated id of `#touch-123-456-789`) would get its own id, remove everything but the last 11 characters (the product code), append `popup-` to the beginning, and then find the element `$("#popup-123-456-789")` and perform an action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about some thing like this..

```
<div class='touch' id='touch-123-456-789'> bla bla </div>
```

on your jquery

```
$('.touch').click(function(){
var id = $(this).attr('id');
id = id.substring(5);

$('#popup' + id).doSomething();

});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is your Html

```
<div class="pop-up" value= "123-456-789">one</div>
<div class="pop-up" value="123-123-123">two</div>
```

This is your jQuery

```
$(".pop-up").click(function(){
  var value = $(this).attr("value");
  var yourElement = "popup-"+value;
  $("#"+yourElement).doSomething(function () {
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to break your id like:

```
 $('.touch').click(function () {
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    id = id.split(/-(.+)?/)[1];
    $('#popup-' + id).html("Hello changed");

 });
```

The .split() here will split the on the first occurrence of "-". So you can do anything with this. 
Lets suppose you have two elements in your html code:

```
 <div class='touch' id='touch-123-456-789'> Touch me </div>
 <div class="popup" id="popup-123-456-789"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This might help. http://jsfiddle.net/79yut/

HTML:

```
<div class="element" id="#touch-123-456-790">Sample element1</div>
<div class="element" id="#touch-123-456-791">Sample element2</div>
<div class="element" id="#touch-123-456-792">Sample element3</div>
<div class="element" id="#touch-123-456-793">Sample element4</div>
<div class="element" id="#touch-123-456-794">Sample element5</div>
```

JS:

```
for (i = 0; i <= $(".element").length; i++) {
    if (i < $(".element").length) {
        var id = $(".element").eq(i).attr("id");
        id = "popup-" + id.substring(7);
        $(".element").eq(i).attr("id", id);
    } else {
        $("#popup-123-456-792").css('color','blue');
    }
}
```